# File in /etc/sudoers.d/ not recognized

Tags: 16.04, sudo

Running a fresh install of Ubuntu server 16.04.1, I tried to add a file in `/etc/sudoers.d/` to give one user root privileges for a certain command.

I added the file `/etc/sudoers.d/servicetest` with the following content:

```
servicetest ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl status *
```

The file `/etc/sudoers` is left untouched. It contains `#includedir /etc/sudoers.d` as the last line.
This setup is unfortunately not working, when executing an appropriate command with sudo as the user `servicetest`, I am still asked for the password. However, if I move the content of the file `/etc/sudoers.d/servicetest` to the end of `/etc/sudoers`, everything is working as expected.

What could be the cause of this issue? How can I get files in `/etc/sudoers.d/` working?

Comment: Maybe `sudo` doesn't accept files with the wrong permissions for security reason (just a guess). What are the */etc/sudoers.d/servicetest* permissions?

Comment: ^^^ +1 in fact the `/etc/sudoers.d/README` file says *"all files in this directory should be mode 0440"*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was not, as answered by IanC, caused by the file permissions (`sudo` happily accepts a file owned by `root:root 0644`, as I can confirm now, although it should of course be `root:root 0440` for security reasons!), but by a newline at the end of the file which was preceded by a windows-style line ending (`\r\n`).

`sudo` only accepts `\n` as line endings.

Comment: Nice that you solved your problem! Did you edit the file in windows? Was curious on how you ended up with the windows newline!

Comment: Yes, I edited a template for the sudoers file in Windows and transferred it via ssh to the Ubuntu machine. And, of course, forgot to convert line endings before doing so. My own stupidity :(

Comment: You should always edit or at least check the file after editing (but before overwriting the original) using the `visudo` tool. Otherwise in certain situations you can lose root access after a wrong edit!

Answer (score 18):

In my CentOS 7, the system would not recognize the file if it had a dot in its name. For instance:

```
/etc/sudoers.d/user.perms                  # This file doesn't work
/etc/sudoers.d/userperms                   # This file does
```

Comment: I've run into the same issue on Ubuntu 18.04, removing the dot and ensuring permissions were set to `0440` and all is well.

Comment: This is also the case on Ubuntu 20.04. Confusingly the OS adds a file "/etc/sudoers.d/99-snapd.conf" , so goodness knows how that has any affect on sudo!

Comment: In Debian 8 (jessie), the system would not recognize the file if it had a dot in its name too.

Answer (score 12):

Apparently, the files that are included in the `/etc/sudoers` file must have 0440 permissions for security reasons. That way only root can edit the file and only the owner and members of the owner group can read it, making it less likely that the file will be used as an attempt to escalate privileges.

You can check the requirements on the included file on `/etc/sudoers.d/README`, but two other requirements are that the filename shouldn't start with a `.` (hidden files) or end with a `~` (convention for backup files).

Credits to @steeldriver for confirming the theory and finding the `/etc/sudoers.d/README` file!

Comment: And that's why one should use `visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/foo` while editing files in `/etc/sudoers.d`.

Comment: Thanks! I did not consider the permission checks to be that harsh (especially since the README says _should be_ and not _must be_). `root:root 0440` and `root:root 0640` doesn't make a difference for me, but it looks like it does for sudo ;)

Comment: Unfortunately, that was not the cause. I just tested it with corrected permissions (`root:root 0440`) and have the same problem as before.

Comment: sudo still need to be used in the cli for the new privileged user, otherwise, password will be asked to enter

Answer (score 2):

I met the same issue with @Guillermo Prandi on Ubuntu 20.04.

If I create a file which has `.conf` extension, it does not work. But, if `.conf` is removed, it works well.

I doubt that `99-snapd.conf` file works well.

As `/etc/sudoers.d/README`, it says, "that **do not** end in '~' or **contain a '.' character**."

@IanC wrote, "that the filename **shouldn't start with a .** (hidden files)", but I guess it may have been updated in the new version.

Answer (score 0):

My sudoers.d directory seemed not working, so i have spend hour trying to figure out why. During that time i have tried:

1. Checking if filename "sudoers.d/rpcuser" contains dot or tilda
2. Setting perfect 0440 root root permissions on that file
3. Viewing all hidden characters and replicating tabs and spaces in my "rpcuser ALL=(ALL)       ALL" as in original "root    ALL=(ALL)       ALL" line
4. Logging in and out with rpcuser after each modification
5. Checking if it relates to some os system reserved status of user "rpcuser"

Nothing helped, at desperation i looked at "# includedir /etc/sudoers.d" line and it appedared i have added extra space between "#" and "include", so that was the problem.